# How to display full image in CircleImageView?

Tags: android

I tried so many different thing such as `scaleType`
and it is not supported by this library. `implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'`

There are other solutions but at the end say that is not supported by this library.

Any idea?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/noticias"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the developer of **CircleImageView**

> While I do understand the requirement for supporting FIT_CENTER in
> case of e.g. company logos, I don't think the result is actually
> desirable. You would have to know the background color of each logo
> and set that as the background color for the circle to not have a hard
> visual break inside the circle. If you still want to go down that
> road, you can always wrap your BitmapDrawable inside a LayerDrawable
> with a ColorDrawable as base layer and proper insets on the
> BitmapDrawable on top.

Discussion on this issue - [here](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/issues/148)

BTW `scaleType` is supported in official **ShapeableImageView**

Add Material Dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Add below to your XML layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circle"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_loading"
    app:strokeColor="#00BA00"
    app:strokeWidth="5dp" />
```

and this to your styles.xml

```
<style name="circle">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: THanks, so there is no way to do using `CircleImageView`?

Comment: No, there isn't any yet, according to its developer.